# Highlight dates in DateListStepPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, date-and-time

I have some data that spans across a whole year from January 8 to December 31, 2023:

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/jCmpsS42", "Table"];
```

Which is shown as a discrete plot:

```
DateListStepPlot[Flatten[data, 1], {{2023, 1, 8}, {2023, 12, 31}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    Automatic}, {Table[{{2023, Month[[1]], 1}, 
      Month[[2]]}, {Month, {Range[13], {"Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", 
         "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez", 
         "Jan"}}\[Transpose]}], None}}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}}, 
 ImageSize -> 1000, AspectRatio -> 1/10]
```

[image]

I selected only the dates for which the variable is greater than 1.654:

```
list = Select[
  Table[{n, Flatten[data, 1][[n]]}, {n, 1, 358}], #[[2]] > 1.654 &]
```

Which gives a list:

```
{{2, 1.92582}, {27, 1.74546}, {29, 1.85577}, {43, 1.85577}, {108, 
  1.74546}, {148, 1.72695}, {182, 1.88484}, {198, 1.99481}, {244, 
  1.7828}, {275, 1.99481}, {323, 1.72695}, {358, 1.74546}}
```

How can I highlight those dates in the DateListStepPlot? Something like this, but for all the twelve dates:

[image]

Also, how can I convert the list to the actual date/month format starting from January 8?

Comment: Please include a small portion of your data.

Comment: @DanielHuber The data is included in the pastebin link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/jCmpsS42", "Table"];

data2 = Table[{DateObject[{2023, 1, 8 + n - 1}], data[[n, 1]]}, {n, Length[data]}];
```

This gives a list of the form
[image]

```
gooddays = Select[data2, #[[2]] > 1.654 &]
```

[image]

```
DateListStepPlot[data2, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}}, ImageSize -> 1000, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/10, Epilog -> {Red, Point /@ gooddays}]
```

[image]